# Check & change specfic folder permissions

Tags: shell-script, permissions

I am trying to check and change a folder's permissions in the shell script. However, it wants to change the permissions even though it's changed.

```
if [ "$(stat -c '%s' /usr/local/src)" == "755" ]; 
then  
echo "Approved!"
else
echo "Wait please, we're changing the permissions"
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/src
fi
```

Error:

```
Wait please, we're changing the permissions
sudo: unable to resolve host john
[sudo] password for john: 
sudo: unable to resolve host john
```

I do type the correct password. I never get `Approved!`, why?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it works, but I change `'%s'` to `'%a'` and it solved my problem :)

Comment: Me neither. `%a` should produce 4 digits. Or did you change `755` to 4 digits?

Comment: no i just changed s with a

Comment: I see. Apparently when the permissions are  0755 it prints just 3 digits. I just checked it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to realise what you're doing.

```
man stat
```

produces among other things the format sequences:

```
  The valid format sequences for files (without --file-system):

   %a     access rights in octal

   %A     access rights in human readable form

   (...)

   %s     total size, in bytes
```

As you can see `%s` is size. As `/usr/local/src` is a directory, the size is `4096`. What you're looking for is the access rights, so either `%a` or `%A`.

The outputs are correspondingly,

```
$ stat -c '%a' /usr/local/src/
2775
```

or just 3 digits if the first octet is `0`; and

```
$ stat -c '%A' /usr/local/src/
drwxrwsr-x
```

In your script, this line:

```
if [ "$(stat -c '%s' /usr/local/src)" == "755" ];
```

compares the output of the substitution `"$(stat -c '%s' /usr/local/src)"` with the string `"755"`. A simple way of debugging this is running the left side alone and examining the result.

```
$ stat -c '%s' /usr/local/src/
4096
```

As you can see, this is not a result, which can represent access rights, though it's similar in format (4 digits). But no permission can be set to `9`, as they're octal. And octal means there are only 8 representing digits, namely 0-7. Here's the moment to check the `man` page of the command `stat`, which I presented at the beginning.

Now it should be easy to figure out how to mend your script.